# Infinite Loading Sceen

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 onto my ASUS ROG Laptop (GL552VW). I am using a usb to boot from. I selected the correct boot option, and extracted the files from the download file. Made an ISO image and booted. I selected "Install Ubuntu", the purple screen loads all of the dots fill up and then it doesn't do anything. The USB stops flashing and nothing happens. I think I read somewhere that I'd have to edit a command or two to get it to load. However, I have no idea what to edit. I've also tried loading Mint onto my laptop and it didn't work. I did try them on my desktop and both OS's worked. So I'm thinking that maybe ASUS hardware doesn't work with the Ubuntu os. I am new to this community so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My system specs are :
Intel I7 6700hq
Nvidia 960m
OCZ Trion SSD (as main storage device)
16gb of DDR4 Ram

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS Menu and set the preference to boot from usb. then it will load from usb.

and yes to boot from usb we need to press key, try function key to load.
When it get loaded choose language preference and go to DO SOMETHING ELSE to dual boot ubuntu with your current OS.